# Automapper from DateTimeOffSet to DateTime and reverse

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

i have a publicDto class like this :

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.0.22.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class SubjectAddressDataDto 
    {
        
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("country", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter))]
        public CountryCodeDto Country { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary>The addrees data are valid since this date</summary>
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("sinceDate", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter))]
        public System.DateTimeOffset SinceDate { get; set; }
    
        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
    
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties; }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }
    
    
    }
```

and and internal model class to automapper like this:

```
    public class SubjectAddressDataDto
    {
        public string FullAddress { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
      
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }

        public DateTime SinceDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in automapping i receive the following error:

```
 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
  
  Mapping types:
  DateTimeOffset -> DateTime
  System.DateTimeOffset -> System.DateTime
  
  Destination Member:
  SinceDate
```

anyone could help me to define a correct mapping config to solve it?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I did it with a value converter. It works for me:

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Src,DestDto>().ForMember(d => d.SinceDate , o => o.ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter()))).ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DateTimeTypeConverter : IValueConverter<DateTimeOffset?, DateTime?>
{
    public DateTime? Convert(DateTimeOffset? source, ResolutionContext context) => source?.LocalDateTime;
    // enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @jrn6270 seems to Map DateTimeOffset to the DateTime type :

```
.ForPath(d => d.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DateTimeOffset.DateTime));
```

However, it does not copy the correct date to the other property...

In order to achieve a correct mapping from DateTimeOffset to DateTime. Add a new:

```
private static DateTime DateTimeOffsetToDateTime(DateTimeOffset source)
{
    string dateTimeString = source.ToString();
    return DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateTimeString).UtcDateTime;
}
```

Then in your mapper add:

```
.ForPath(d => d.SomeDateTimeProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => DateTimeOffsetToDateTime(s.SomeDateTimeProperty)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom type converter with implement of ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination> interface and add it to your profile class with ConvertUsing method.
Doc from automapper: [custom type converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)

Comment: `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` works by default, no converter needed. But the reverse needs a converter, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset).

Comment: CreateMap<DateTimeOffset, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(s => ConvertFromDateTimeOffset(s));

            CreateMap<BFBSubjectAddressDataDto, SubjectAddressDataDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SinceDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ConvertFromDateTimeOffset(src.SinceDate)));

anyone of this work fine, the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the DateTime property of the DateTimeOffset variable when you are doing the mapping: `.ForPath(d => d.DateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DateTimeOffset.DateTime));`